# Internet Explorer 10 crashes when printing

Tags: windows-7, internet-explorer, printing

- The crash message states it is a BEX error, which is apparently a buffer overflow
- The Fault module is stackhash, which apparently means no module, so it returns a hash of the stack
- The crash occurs when printing to any printer including cutePDF and excepting XPS
- Crash occurs with all addons disabled (IE run with -extoff switch)
- BEX64 occurs when trying to print XPS. I'm assuming XPS viewer uses IE to print, or they both use the same binary somewhere
- IE10 is in software rendering mode. Hardware rendering mode causes IE to crash on starting (identical error). Have updated graphics drivers (Intel HD) and unplugged external graphics extender for 2nd monitor without luck
- Printing works from Firefox and Chrome and Office Apps
- The machine is fully up-to-date with MS patching, as is IE10

Is this a bug in the Windows 7 or Internet Explorer?

Comment: I don't think this is enough information to diagnose it. What you really need is to fill out a report at http://connect.microsoft.com/IE and to upload a dump file.

Comment: Have you tried excluding IE from DEP mode? I'm not even sure how to do that, but I know it could help.

Comment: follow the steps I posted here: http://pastebin.com/VDDuMrgb and uplaod the dumps and add a link here.